# Binary conversion issues

Tags: java, recursion, methods, binary, int

I am working on a code that is supposed to take in a users input, then convert it to binary with base 2 through 9. (Sorry if these are the wrong terms, completely new to the idea of binary.) I have the code done, but there is something missing. This is what it is supposed to out put when the user types in "245"

```
 converted to base 2 = 11110101
 converted to base 3 = 100002
 converted to base 4 = 3311
 converted to base 5 = 1440
 converted to base 6 = 1045
 converted to base 7 = 500
 converted to base 8 = 365
 converted to base 9 = 302
```

However, this is what I get for my output:

```
converted to base 2 = 1111010
converted to base 3 = 10000
converted to base 4 = 331
converted to base 5 = 144
converted to base 6 = 104
converted to base 7 = 50
converted to base 8 = 36
converted to base 9 = 30
```

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //ask user for number
    Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
    int input = k.nextInt();
    System.out.println();

    //this loop converts the number into each base from 2 to 9
    //for each base the loop calls the convertNumber() method to do the conversion
    for(int i=2; i<=9; i++) {
      System.out.print("converted to base " + i + " = ");
      convertNumber(input, i);
      System.out.println();}
}


 /*
   * Recursive method that prints the given number in the given base
   * example:  if n = 13 and base = 2 (binary) then 1101 should be displayed
   */
 private static void convertNumber(int n, int base) {
 if (n >= base) {
      n = n/base;
      convertNumber(n, base);     
      int r = (n % base);
      System.out.print(r);

    }



  } //end convertNumber
}//ends Tester
```

Comment: I assume this is for homework or something. Otherwise you could just use [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Comment: Yes, and I always have problems with that code on my computer for some reason.. I always get an error. One of our books codes had that and in order for the program to run I had to take that code out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a bug in the convert number routine, if n is not GE than the base, you need an else, where you print out whatever n is.  This is why all of your responses are missing the last digit.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! I have it where I can get it to print out the whole thing, but backwards. 


'int r = n%base:
System.out.print(r);
if (n>=base){
n=n/base;
convertNumber(n);
}'

But I'm going to try what you said and see if that works. 
Thank you! 
I appreciate the help.

Comment: So I figured out it's just printing everything backwards so my problem is not at the end of the code, it's the beginning. It only takes the remainder of the 2nd n/base(if n=245, then it would start taking remainder at n=122).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the base case: you stop when n >= base, and never print out the final digit.  Instead, keep going until n == 0; that means that you've converted and printed *all* the digits.

Comment: When I change the if statement to 
    if(n>=0) {} Then I get a stack overflow error? Any suggestions?

Comment: @GabbieGrapes My suggestion is not to program by trial-and-error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys! Its probably more complicated than it needs to be, but it works for now.

```
private static void convertNumber(int n, int base) {
     int m = n;
    int j=1;       
    if (n >= base ||n==0) {
       n = n/base;
    convertNumber(n, base);
      if (j != 1){
    int r = (n % base);
    System.out.print(r);}
    else {
      int r = (m % base);
      System.out.print(r);
    j++;}}
    else{
      int r = (n % base);
      System.out.print(r);}
  } //end convertNumber
```

Thanks for your help.